# Calculating harmonic sum

Tags: performance, algorithm, c

The problem is that I have executed the program for the last hour and it hasn't returned a value till now for input 10<sup>22</sup>. How can I make the program a bit faster? How can I increase the efficiency of program? Is there a faster algorithm?

I have Intel Core2 Duo (2.93GHz).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    unsigned long long n;
    double m;
    double sum=0;
    scanf("%llu", &n);
    while (n>0) {
        m=1.0/n;
        sum+=m;
        n--;
    }
    printf("%lf",sum);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You have an accuracy issue: even though you compute the smaller fractions first, the accumulated error after 10^22 iterations is substantial.  I wouldn't be surprised if the result was completely inaccurate.  You should analyse this seriously before focussing on speed.

Comment: Also note that `"%lf"` is equivalent to `"%f"`  `l` has no effect on `f` in `printf`, unlike `scanf`.  The format to print `long double` is `"%Lf"`.

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate my comment about accuracy, I wrote a small test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned long long n;
    double sum = 0;
    float fsum = 0;
    long double lsum = 0;

    if (argc > 1)
        n = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    else
        scanf("%llu", &n);

    while (n > 0) {
        /* computing using double arithmetic */
        double m = 1.0 / n;
        sum += m;
        /* computing using float arithmetic */
        float fm = (float)1 / n;
        fsum += fm;
        /* computing using long double arithmetic */
        long double lm = (long double)1 / n;
        lsum += lm;
        n--;
    }
    printf("long double: %Lf\n", lsum);
    printf("double: %f, delta=%Lg\n", sum, lsum - sum);
    printf("float: %f, delta=%f\n", fsum, sum - fsum);
    return 0;
}
```

The following tests give this output:

```
~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./t41 10000000
long double: 16.695311
double: 16.695311, delta=-1.12868e-13
float: 16.686031, delta=0.009280

real  0m0.257s
user  0m0.244s
sys   0m0.004s

~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./t41 100000000
long double: 18.997896
double: 18.997896, delta=4.51783e-13
float: 18.807919, delta=0.189978

real  0m2.585s
user  0m2.558s
sys   0m0.010s

~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./t41 1000000000
make: `t41' is up to date.
long double: 21.300482
double: 21.300482, delta=1.79655e-12
float: 18.807919, delta=2.492563

real  0m25.287s
user  0m25.116s
sys   0m0.073s
```

My machine is not very fast, but it would take 10^13 seconds to complete the
calculation for 10^22 using your code.  Given the estimated age of the universe,
5.10^17 seconds, you should kill the process and think about a better algorithm.

Looking at the accumulated error for just 10^9 iterations between `long double` and `double`,
computing in `double` for 10^13 more iterations would given useless results.

Comment: Why should my code acumulate error? I don't get your program please explain! Thank you very much!

Comment: Your code accumulates errors because floating point operations have limited accuracy.  Mine does too.  My program illustrates how this limited accuracy quicky becomes problematic. `float` computation is completely off, `double` is visibly less accurate than `long double`.  If `n` becomes very large, even `long double` would not be accurate enough.

Comment: The harmonic sum of integers between 1 and `n` converges to `log(n)+γ`, γ (gamma) being the Euler-Mascheroni constant.  Check this for other algorithms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant